# How can I stop ingress spoofed email to my company

Tags: email, exchange

I am receiving spoofed emails to my private company address, for example from HP, IBM, RSA and ISACA, but these are not actually from those companies.

How can I stop these kind of emails coming into my organization? I am using MS Exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E-mail can be made to appear like it came from a big organization?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/e-mail-can-be-made-to-appear-like-it-came-from-a-big-organization). There are also many other similar questions here, search for "sender spoofing email".

Answer (score 1):

Large companies usually have correct setup for SPF and DKIM.
For example, Google has SPF

```
gmail.com descriptive text "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"
_spf.google.com descriptive text "v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"
```

and DKIM (header in each email)

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
    h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
    bh=0KZKx3IrvM+lVU2slBR2lDRtzAfXwXyEKx+wPABZ83U=;
    b=Hv9yEMMaAARk9hz0lndU2LpQC9aXnBG29nOHyjbP85j/Wb8T97OtdbFJYPPNG2JBQ7
    ...
```

The first is a DNS record where you can see from which IPs emails of these sender domains could arrive. You can then discard all emails that appear to say they from some domain, but source IP is not in the SPF record.

DKIM uses cryptographic signing for same purpose. So if email gets originated on permitted server, you could be able to check signature and tell that this email is good, and to discard it otherwise.

There is software which makes all these checks. For example, there is opendkim software, which integrates into postfix or sendmail system and checks all incoming email's signature (and signs your outgoing emails).

Answer (score 0):

Check SenderId in the DNS record of the sender's domain. This should list the valid sender IP addresses if properly configured. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID

Answer (score 0):

DMARC on SPF+DKIM. If you are using bare MS Exchange, you best implement linux pass-through SMTP. It acts as a front end to Exchange. Also known as a smarthost. It's best to implement DMARC, SPF, DKIM, antivir, spamassassin (i.e. bayesian filtering) on Linux.